# Send jpg and texts from flash to php in ONE CLICK 

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, text, jpeg

Can give an example of how to send jpg and some texts from flash to php in ONE CLICK ? I`m realy annoyed of that ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all relax :)
 
Then try to clarify... 
What's your specific problem?

1/ Sending variables to PHP
There are a lot of tutorials out there regarding Flash / PHP communication. 
Here's a video tutorial
http://blog.phpmoz.org/two-way-flash-php-communication-adobe-flash-tutorial-as3/

2/Image encoding in AS3
This article may help , although it goes a bit further than what you're asking
http://designreviver.com/tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash/

3/Do all of the above with one Click
Why not try an introduction to AS3. I always recommend Colin Mook's Lost Actionscript Week End video series on AdobeTV

---

No, I don't really have a link for static methods. Think of it as a way to encapsulate functionality that doesn't affect a specific instance of a class. Let's say for example that you're using various forms in your application and you would like to validate them, you could create a Validation class with some static methods.

In that example, the Validation class clearly doesn't care about validating itself, it's only a container for accessing the validation methods wherever you need them.

```
   var email:TextField;
   //whenever that field has been filled , you could validate it like that:
   var valid:Boolean = ValidationClass.emailValidate( email.text );
```

As you can see, in order to access the static methods of a class, you don't need to instantiate the class, which also explains why static methods are not meant to affect a specific instance of a class.

hope it helps! if it's still unclear , I'm sure a little Googling plus some experimentation should help ;)

Comment: Do you know any link that describes "Static" command in full details ? I want to fully understand it. ..... Cheers